# Regex with dynamically variable

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a file with enormous strings inside it and I need separate them out by using the pattern : "Nº ARQUIVO:" . But for this, first i need identify the first occurrence of the sub-string "Nº ARQUIVO:" and then, create the real Regular Expression, like this:

First i identify the occurrence of the first "Nº ARQUIVO:" http://www.regexr.com/3c652

So:

```
let string = 'THE HUGE STRING'; // I'm not going to paste here because the string is too big.

let reg    = /.*?MINISTÉRIO DO TRABALHO E EMPREGO.*?Nº ARQUIVO:\s([\w-]+)/;

let match  = reg.exec(string)[0];
```

output:

```
PA8Nm01j0oI0000-9
```

Now, i need use a second regex to delimit the start position and the end postion of the string that is to be extracted.

```
let reg2   = new RegExp('(.*?MINISTÉRIO DO TRABALHO E EMPREGO.*'+ match + '.*?Z6:\\s[\\w]+\\b)')
let match2 = reg.exec(string)[0];
```

output:

```
All the text from the MINISTÉRIO DO TRABALHO E EMPREGO **** the first Z6: 0 after the last PA8Nm01j0oI0000-9
```

I would like to know if it is possible to replace the above two steps, with a single step in a single regex expression.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: How can i use just one string to achieve the same result.

Comment: @FátimaAlves : I edited the question to clarify based on your comment above. You could check if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes! Thanks @WhirlMind

Comment: Please check [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kR7sU0/1) - is it what you need?

Comment: yes, post as an answer @stribizhev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
.*?MINISTÉRIO DO TRABALHO E EMPREGO.*?Nº ARQUIVO:\s([\w-]+).*?Z6:\s\w+\b
|-------------------------- 1 ----------------------------|--- 2 ------|
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kR7sU0/1)

However, this regex is too inefficient. Use another, identical one, but that is much more efficient:

```
MINISTÉRIO DO TRABALHO E EMPREGO(?:[^N]*(?:N(?!º ARQUIVO:)[^N]*)*)Nº ARQUIVO:\s([\w-]+)(?:[^Z]*(?:Z(?!6:\s\w+)[^Z]*)*)Z6:\s\w+\b
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kR7sU0/2)

The difference is that lazy matching is replaced with "unrolled" contructs (see ["Unrolling the loop"](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) article)

In JS, you can use

```
var re = /MINISTÉRIO DO TRABALHO E EMPREGO(?:[^N]*(?:N(?!º ARQUIVO:)[^N]*)*)Nº ARQUIVO:\s([\w-]+)(?:[^Z]*(?:Z(?!6:\s\w+)[^Z]*)*)Z6:\s\w+\b/g;
var str = "<<HUGE_STRING>>";
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // m[0] = whole match
    // m[1] = 'PA8Nm01j0oI0000-9'-like submatches
}
```